# Date and Time wrong at my Centos Server

Tags: linux, centos

I have Centos6 at my Servers(text mode), When I stalled it I choosed my location, but date now is go back one day ago. I change it again but when I shutdown or restart my server it get the date one day ago again. How is the right way to configure date time and locations. I am working text mode, then I need commands or file to modify wit the right values.

Thanks

Comment: Did you check the date/time via the servers' BIOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to configure NTP servers. [RHEL sites](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sect-Date_and_Time_Configuration-Command_Line_Configuration-Network_Time_Protocol.html) seem to have a good solution for that.

Comment: I did it and everything is right now. Thanks a lot!!!!